# How to return gzipped content with AWS API Gateway

Tags: aws-api-gateway, http-accept-encoding

We have developed an application that offers serveral rest services and supports `Accept-Encoding` header to return compressed content through `Content-Encoding:gzip` header value.

This application is deployed on ec2 instances on aws and when we send a request with `Accept-Encoding` value set the response is correctly built.

We want to expose this api by using api gateway but it is just working for not compressing requests. When we send a request asking for gzipped content the `Content-Encoding` header is set correctly but the response content is corrupt.

Do we have to set some special parameter or configuration in integration response or method response steps?

Regards.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since Dec 19, 2017. AWS API Gateway has encoding support.

After the API is created, just go to Settings and select Content Encoding Enable.

[image: See example]

Also [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/amazon-api-gateway-supports-content-encoding-for-api-responses/) is the AWS official release post.

Comment: If you manage CORS headers in your app, don't forget to allow any necessary response headers in your pre-flight response.  I was missing `Content-Encoding` and despite having this API option enabled, API Gateway was not compressing my responses.  The header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Content-Encoding` in my response to the CORS OPTION pre-flight seems to have fixed it.

Comment: Also I think I had to deploy the API to the stage after enabling this setting.  Even though nothing else changed in my API, and the setting appears to be set at a 'api' level as opposed to an 'individual stage' level, I didn't see the compression in my prod stage until I re-deployed the API to that stage.

Comment: @CarlG What do you mean you had to deploy to Stage? What if I was working on stage already and modified the settings to enable compression?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, API Gateway does not currently support HTTP compression. However, it is in consideration for future development.

For now, you will need to return uncompressed content from your endpoint (i.e. omit Accept-Encoding header) in order to proxy it through API Gateway.

If it works for your use case you could alternatively base64 encode the compressed content, proxy it through API Gateway, and decode it on the client.

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: It does support it now, since 2018 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-receive-response-with-compressed-payload.html

Comment: @Sigex yes but only for REST APIs. Http apis dont support compression yet.

Answer (score 7):

Only a workaround, but [if you set `Accept-Encoding: identity` you should receive the result correctly](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=241530) (contrary to the linked discussion I have found it works for POST *and* GET).

Comment: After pulling my hair out for hours and hours, I can confirm this obscure piece of info works. With this issue with GZipping and  mucking around with getting CORS to work, it has been a nightmare getting set up. I am sure thousands have not had my perseverance and just given up. Get your act together Amazon.

Comment: @Lobos Same here, I've been struggling with the setup for 2 days now. It's been a nightmare.

Comment: Update: I've given up.

Comment: So have I; installed Kong instead! API gateway is pretty expensive anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is a bit old, I'd like to add an answer since this question is top-most viewed one. In fact, there are 2 scenarios related to returning the compressed content.

The first scenario is when you want API Gateway to compress the content. As the accepted answer suggests, you can enable the content encoding on your API then deploy it.

The second scenario is your integration endpoint already compressed the result and you just want to bypass it via API Gateway. The traditional workaround was configuring it as a binary media type. However, this might be problematic since it will begin to treat all response with the media type as a binary. Additionally, if you need to deal with multiple media types, your only choice would be setting it as '*'. If you're using non-proxy integration, you will lose a chance to transform the result.

To address the second issue, now API Gateway implicitly assumes a response result as binary when a proxy integration is used AND the content is encoded (the response has Content-Encoding with the value other than 'identity'). You don't need to configure binary media types any more when these conditions are met.
However, if you're returning the actual binary media (e.g. image, video), you still need to configure them as binary media type(s).

You might wonder what happens when you have both scenarios. The short answer is that API Gateway will not compress again when the response already has Content-Encoding header.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I'm dealing with the second scenario (my integration Lambda returns gzipped content, which I tested stand-alone) but the API gateway is messing up the response. My Lambda returns the header "Content-Encoding":"gzip" which I tested in the API Gateway web console. Any ideas how to get API gateway to treat the response as binary?

Comment: @JacobMouka and everyone else who finds my comment: I encoded the response body in base64 and in the lambda return object there's a flag "isBase64Encoded" in HTTP API.

Answer (score 2):

I made it work by adding `Accept-Encoding` to AWS API Gateway `Integration Request`

**Step 1:** 
Go to AWS API Gateway console, click on `Integration Request`
[image]

**Step 2:**
Add `Accept-Encoding` to `HTTP Headers` section, value `'identity'` (need single quotes)
[image]

**Step 3:**
Click `Actions` -> `Deploy API`

If you're using `AWS CloudFormation`, you can add 
`yaml
Integration:
    RequestParameters:
    integration.request.header.Accept-Encoding: "'identity'`

Answer (score 0):

To allow GZipped content from HTTP proxy endpoint you can add */* in "Binary media types" found at "Binary Support" section of your API.

Comment: Quotes from another source must be properly attributed and formatted as *text*, not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to return a compressed body in your lambda through the Api gateway you have to return a base64 encoded byte array. A c# example would be:

```
APIGatewayProxyResponse response = new
        {
            statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
            headers = new { ContentEncoding = "gzip", ContentType = "application/json" },
            body = Convert.ToBase64String(<your gzip byte[]>),
            isBase64Encoded = true
        };
```