# AWS API Gateway return response as GZIP

Tags: amazon-web-services, gzip, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb, content-encoding

I have a application deployed in API gateway i.e APIG -> ELB -> ECS. When I request for gzip, i.e Accept: application/json; Accept-Encoding:application/gzip. The content is unreadable by client (browser,fiddler). But the same request triggered via ELB comes clean. Is API Gateway adding/removing any bytes from the response. Can any one help me to tweak it ?

@ankit : it is related to same question. But now that API gateway have binary support and I configured it to return it that way. But the question is compressed response is incorrect. Fiddler and other clients are not able to decompress it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return gzipped content with AWS API Gateway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39453097/how-to-return-gzipped-content-with-aws-api-gateway)

Comment: There was an issue previously where "HTTP Proxy" requests would remove the Content-Encoding header, causing clients to not see the content as gzipped. This should no longer be the case. 

Please provide more details about your configuration (example request/response, evidence of configuration for binary support in API Gateway) if you want further assistance debugging this.