# AWS API Gateway ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, aws-api-gateway

In my use case, API Gateway serves as an HTTP proxy, using default settings following [official tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-http.html).

It's tested working in test console or via curl. But if I access the link in browser or make an AJAX call, I'll get `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`.

It seems that API Gateway corrupt the content. [Related issue](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=774903).

Is there a way to forbid API Gateway changing my content? I set `Content Handling` to `passthrough`, but clearly it's changing my content.

Comment: You need to use `curl --compressed ...` if you want to try to duplicate the behavior.  Without this option, curl won't send `Accept-Encoding: gzip`, and without that, you're unlikely to receive a response that is improperly encoded, since it shouldn't be encoded at all.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot Is there a way to forbid APIGW changing my content? I set `Content Handling` to `passthrough`, but clearly it's changing my content.

Comment: You may be up against a current design limitation in API Gateway, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39458711/1695906).  A possible workaround may be to add a static integration request header `Accept-Encoding` with value `'identity'`.

Comment: This fixed my issue perfectly! Can you post it as an anwser? I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a static integration request header `Accept-Encoding` with value `'identity'`, so that AWS won't tamper your request.

Comment: Could you please explain  where  to add it ?

Comment: `AWS won't' tamper your request` is it was API Gateway won't tamper the request or origin server/function , where the header should be placed, Answer deserves to be more precise to help more people.