# How to enable GZIP in .NET Serverless Application on AWS Lambda?

Tags: .net-core, aws-lambda, serverless

I created a new .NET Serverless Application and published it on Lambda and I want to enable the GZIP (Br) Compression.

However, it gives me this Error: ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED

It's working properly on localhost.

I have already enabled the Compression option on API Gateway but it doesn't help.

What should I set up to make it working?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815649/aws-api-gateway-err-content-decoding-failed-in-browser

Answer (score 0):

Content compression is handled by the API gateway, which sends and receives uncompressed content to and from lambdas -- lambdas are and should be unaware of any compression that might happening.

Here's the documentation for enabling compression at the API gateway: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-gzip-compression-decompression.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-enable-compression.html

Comment: It's an perfect answered my question! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not totally true, you might want to gzip inside lambda to avoid hitting the body size limit of 6mb